# Determine amplitude of graph

Tags: graphing-functions

[image]I generate a graph using X and Y column of data (its time vs voltage graph X represent time and Y represent voltage column)

Need to work
To calculate quarter of in one period of cycle. (place marker for better representation)

So I am looking some algo/Mathmatics input which can give some direction

If I map my work, this below  url provide info about period and amplitude of the waveform But They
have equation

https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/amplitude-period-frequency-phase-shift.html

In a similar way, I need to calculate amplitude in one cycle.
How should I convert data point to the equation.

Input. similiar I have 1000 points.

```
9.99999999985252e-11 0.0000
1.99999999998744e-10 0.0000
2.99999999998964e-10 9.0000e-02
3.9999999999876e-10 0.1800
4.99999999998979e-10 0.1800
5.99999999998775e-10 0.1800
6.99999999998994e-10 0.1800
7.9999999999879e-10 0.1800
8.99999999999009e-10 0.1800
9.99999999998805e-10 0.1800
1.09999999999902e-09 0.1800
1.19999999999882e-09 0.1800
1.29999999999904e-09 0.1800
1.39999999999883e-09 0.1800
1.49999999999905e-09 0.1800
1.59999999999885e-09 0.1800
1.69999999999907e-09 0.1800
1.79999999999886e-09 0.1800
1.89999999999908e-09 0.1800
1.99999999999888e-09 0.1800
2.0999999999991e-09 0.1800
2.19999999999889e-09 0.1800
2.29999999999911e-09 0.1800
2.39999999999891e-09 0.1800
2.49999999999913e-09 0.1800
2.59999999999892e-09 0.1800
2.69999999999914e-09 0.1800
2.79999999999894e-09 0.1800
2.89999999999916e-09 0.1800
2.99999999999895e-09 0.1800
3.09999999999917e-09 0.1800
3.19999999999897e-09 0.1800
3.29999999999877e-09 0.1800
3.39999999999898e-09 0.1800
3.49999999999878e-09 0.1800
3.599999999999e-09 0.1800
3.6999999999988e-09 0.1800
```

Comment: Your function is not a sine or a cosine, so it doesn't make sense to "convert data point to the equation" with the equation as given

Comment: As for the problem of determining amplitude and period, that is more a programming problem than a mathematics problem. What software are you using for this data?

Comment: I am looking some mathmatics function which can do similiar thing. Programming I will take care. I am not using any software and placing plot using matplotlib

Comment: What exactly would you call "matplotlib" if not software? in any case, please clarify what you mean by "some mathmatics function which can do similiar thing".

Comment: I mean, can we determine solve problem through mathmatics if we have data point is X and Y. Determine one cycle. Determine ampliture

Comment: I saw some post which convert data point to equation so idea come in my mind but as of now totally blank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112010/discussion-between-user765443-and-ben-grossmann).

Comment: I think I am stupid, what about this, if store start point of Y axis and repeat again than it is hlaf cycle. than if determine x-point than take half value it will solve my purpose